# Zebra cURL returing é as question mark

Tags: curl, special-characters

I am using http://stefangabos.ro/wp-content/docs/Zebra_cURL/Zebra_cURL/Zebra_cURL.html#methodoption to make a curl call.

Everything goes right but the return of special characters, they return like a question mark with a black diamond around it (in Chrome).

How can I solve this problem?

```
    $this->curl->queue();

    $this->curl->cache('application/cache', 60);

    $this->curl->option(array(
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('text/plain;charset=UTF-8'),
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'UTF-8'
    ));

    $this->curl->get($list, 'callback');

    $this->curl->start();
```

Comment: By _converting_ data that is not in UTF-8 _to_ UTF-8 before sending it to the browser saying it _was_ UTF-8.

Comment: Okay thanks, and how do I do this exactly? As I'm oblivous about this matter.